# Windows Phone 8, Есть ли что-то подобное UITableView как в iOS ?

Tags: c#, windowsphone, windows-phone-8

Всем привет! В общем задача построить таблицу из ответа от сервера. Делаю пост запрос, сервер отдает джсон, а дальше мне нужно построить таблицу, обрабатывать клик на элемент таблицы и добавлять элементы в конец таблицы, когда пользователь проскроллил до конца вниз. Есть ли что-то подобное? Нашёл ListBox, но не могцу найти адекватного примера реализации всего функционала котоырй я перечислил. 
Спасибо всем!

Comment: Графических элементов, который представляют табличную информацию, есть множество. `ListView`, `StackPanel`, `DataGrid`, что угодно.

Опишите весь функционал, который вам нужен.

Отправление запроса и разбор JSON не относятся к функциональности таблицы, не понимаю, зачем вы вообще о них упоминаете. Построение таблицы из коллекции данных работает с тем же `ListBox`'ом из коробки. Добавление элементов реализуется либо автоматически (используйте `ObservableCollection`), либо вручную. Click и OnScroll обрабатывается в code behind. Чего не хватает?

Answer (score 1):

[Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752271.aspx)

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.